# What are some best practices for data(image) normalization?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, normalization, image-scaling, batch-normalization

I know a few methods like below:

1. Mean normalization(image-image.mean/image.stddev) on each image(here mean is scalar value)
2. Mean normalization(image-avgmean/avgstddev) taken on entire dataset(here mean is vector(2d/3d).
3. Max-min normalization(image-image.min/image.max-image.min) on each image(min and max are scalar)
4. Scaling dividing image by 255. to make it between [0-1] range.

I am just asking which one is proven to be better, with relu and if it make any sense then with Batch-normalization.